# Is it illegal for Congress to pass an unconstitutional law?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court, congress

If Congress passes a law and SCOTUS strikes it down, are there any consequences for Congress other than the law not being enforceable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There are no consequences for Congress.

This follows, in part, from the [Speech or Debate Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_or_Debate_Clause), which is a clause in the United States Constitution (Article I, Section 6, Clause 1). The clause states that members of both Houses of Congress:

> shall in all Cases, except Treason, Felony, and Breach of the Peace,
> be privileged from Arrest during their attendance at the Session of
> their Respective Houses, and in going to and from the same; and for
> any Speech or Debate in either House, they shall not be questioned in
> any other Place.